# Use a list as cursor.execute parameter with dotenv

Tags: python, postgresql, list, database-cursor, dotenv

I am using the dotenv framework to connect my python script to a postgres database.
I have a list of ids and want to delete all the rows containing thoses ids

```
ids_to_delete = df["food_id"].tolist()


conn = create_conn()        
       with conn.cursor() as cursor:            
         sql = "DELETE FROM food_recommandations.food_categorisation
         WHERE food_categorisation.food_id = %(ids)s "
         cursor.execute(sql, {"ids":ids_to_delete} )
         cursor.close()
         conn.close()
```

This must delete all the rows containing thoses ids

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `=` with list because your columns doesn't have lists stored in it. Single cell contains one integer id. So what you are looking for is SQL `in` operator

```
sql = "DELETE FROM food_recommandations.food_categorisation
         WHERE food_categorisation.food_id in %(ids)s "
cursor.execute(sql, {"ids":tuple(ids_to_delete)} )
```

Comment: Convert the list to tuple instead. Sorry I can't understand the language. 

`cursor.execute(sql, {"ids": tuple(ids_to_delete)} )`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your obscurification manager (dotenv framework) translates the structure `{"ids":tuple(ids_to_delete)}` to an array before transmitting to Postgres. That then required a slight alteration in you query. The `in` expects a *delimited list* which is close tp the same to you and I is vary different to Postgres. With an array use the predicate `= ANY`. So the query from @WasiHaider becomes:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM food_recommandations.food_categorisation
         WHERE food_categorisation.food_id = ANY %(ids)s "
cursor.execute(sql, {"ids":tuple(ids_to_delete)} )
```

Note: Not tested - no data.

If successful credit to @WasiHaider.